# migrate Android sqlite database to another app

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, android-database

I have an app with a sqlite database and user data. I have made a new app but it uses the same structure and I would like to migrate the data from the first app.
Both apps need to be in the app store, therebefore I cannot just update the app.

Is there any way to import/export the database to another app?
I checked out Room https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room
but I'm not sure if it's possible with it.

Thanks!

Comment: If the intention is both apps can exist on a device, could you expose the data in the first app with a `ContentProvider`? You can use a `signature` permission level if both apps are signed with the same keystore for security.